# Visual Composer element extensions/custom elements

Tags: wordpress

I am using visual composer to create a WordPress site.
I have been trying to figure out how I would go about extending the functionality of visual composer elements, or failing that creating my own.

Specifically I would like to add a description to the "Team Member" element that appears on top of the image when the team member is moused over.

I have had a look at the VC documentation but it has not been able to help me thus far.

Comment: team member element is not in visual composer native shortcodes. so you are already using some of extentesion for visual composer that creates it for you. The kb.wpbakery.com have developers how-tos to create custom elements or modify current. As for description you should modify template.